# How to Embed SQL in Jasper Reports with Struts 2

Tags: java, spring, configuration, struts2, jasper-reports

```xml
<action name="myJasperTest" class="com.focus.web.action.asset.AssetAction" method="setData">
     <result name="success" type="jasper">
          <param name="location">reports/check_list/Check_List.jasper</param>
          <param name="connection">connection</param>
          <param name="dataSource">myList</param>
          <param name="format">HTML</param>
     </result>
</action>
```

This is my struts action for displaying the jasper report. 
I am using a embed SQL in jasper report. So then I will have to set connection param. 
Since I am using Spring in project I did auto-wired to data-source and returned a connection from my respective action class and what should be the value for `dataSource`?

I am not having any list need to send report from action class and if I don't mention the  `dataSource` it says `dataSource` is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `dataSource` should be the list of objects. For example

```
//List to use as JasperReports dataSource parameter.
private List<MyBean> myDataSource;

public List<MyBean> getMyDataSource() {
    return myDataSource;
}
```

This is not a dataSource bean used by the Spring to manage connections.

the `connection` parameter is available since version 2.1.7:

> connection - (2.1.7+) JDBC Connection which can be passed to the
>   report instead of dataSource

Comment: i was getting the connection from spring data source and assigned it to **connection param**.
I did't use it for **dataSource param**. And I believe to set the report parameters we need to use a **Hashmap** instead of  bean list

Comment: Actually, it doesn't matter. But to set parameters you should use `reportParameters` param.

Comment: yes i am using **reportParameters param** but what to do with **dataSource param**. And what is the strut2-jasper-plugin version compatiable with jasper 3.5. and what is different between jasperreport and net.sf.jasperreports.

Comment: no, you didn't use it, and these questions aren't in the question, so I didn't answer them.

Comment: yep in the code snap i haven't mentioned it sorry. again i thought the problem could be due some other reason such as version incompatible. so that is why i included those also  `<param name="exportParameters">parameterMap</param>`

Comment: The plugin requires jasperreports 3.1.2